# AuthenticationProvider with passwordEncoder

Tags: spring-boot, encoding, spring-security, oauth-2.0

When I try to use password encoder to check. It hasn't worked, I see "Bad password".
How should I receive authentication.getCredentials() to check passwords?

If I save user without encoding and try to log in, it works.

```
@Component
public class AuthClient implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {


        String username = authentication.getName();
        String checkPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(authentication.getCredentials().toString());

        Client client = this.clientRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (client == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username/password");
        }

        String password = client.getPassword();
        if (!password.equals(checkPassword)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad password");
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = translate();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password,authorities);

    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> translate() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CLIENT"));
        return authorities;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class
                .isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it wrong if you want to test two passwords you need to use passwordEncoder like this:

```
    String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (!passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, client.getPassword())) {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad password");
    }
```